# VS2012 hangs up when you Install Nuget Package Manager

Tags: visual-studio-2012

Hi guys my VS2012 installation started Hanging up with a `VS2012 busy ballon` in the Taskbar. This happens when I try to add some new Class or Controller in a MVC project. I reset VS2012 which didnt work. Then I uninstalled all Extension and it was working. Now all my other Extensions are reinstalled and working with the VS2012 installation perfectly except NUGET Package Manager. Any ideas on how to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried uninstall nuget package manager from Tools -> Extension and Update? After uninstall, restart Visual studio to make it take effect. Then you can install nuget package manager again from the Tools -> Extension and Update -> online tab.

Comment: Was the NuGet shown as installed from Tools -> Extension and Update? What error did you get when you try to run nuget package manager?

Comment: Yes it was the same Nuget. The Nuget installs sucessfully with no errors. But after I restart VS and open a project and try to add a Class or Controller VS just puts a balloon in taskbar saying its busy.